# update with concat in where clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `devolucion_medicamento` (
  `id_devolucion_medicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_devolucion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_medicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fec_mov` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `activo` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lote` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fec_venc` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tamano` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `inventario` varchar(45) NOT NULL
)
```

and i have to update the value of "inventario" where id_medicamento,fec_venc,tamano and inventario are equals to some concatenated string value that i get from an app.

I thought on something like this

```
 UPDATE devolucion_medicamento
SET
inventario="AAAAAA",
WHERE concat(id_medicamento,lote,fec_venc,tamano,inventario)="54062018-09-308"
```

but i don't know if it is possible in mysql.
I'm having this error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE concat(id_medicamento,lote,fec_venc,tamano,inventario)="54062018-09-308"' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

I'm too new to comment...  but it appears there is a comma after inventario="AAAAAA".  If so, MySQL is expecting another set expression.